# What code is this?

Tags: php, c, api

Please consider the following code snippet:

From php-5.3.1/ext/session/session.c:

```
PHPAPI char *php_session_create_id(PS_CREATE_SID_ARGS)
…
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
…
/* maximum 15+19+19+10 bytes */
spprintf(&buf, 0, "%.15s%ld%ld%0.8F", remote_addr ? 
remote_addr : "", tv.tv_sec, (long int)tv.tv_usec, 
php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C) * 10);
…
return buf;
}
```

I have found it on the internet. But I can't understand what code is this. I guess this is the implementation of a php function in C++. If yes, then please explain me how php calles c++ function in it?

Comment: PHP is interpreted and ends up running as C code.

Comment: PHP is interpreted and ends up running as machine code. The interpreter is written in C :-)

Comment: Chris: You are wrong See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720488/how-exactly-is-a-php-script-executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shocking truth is that PHP is written in C. You are looking at the source of PHP itself, or need to explain the question further.

Comment: What does it mean that php is written in C? Does each function of php implemented with the same name in C, and when you call a php function the C function is being called itself? Can I say that PHP is a lib written in C and when I write PHP, actually I write C by using PHP library?

Comment: @Narek The PHP interpreter is a program, which is written in C. You might want to google "interpreter" to understand what that is.

Comment: @Narek: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720488/how-exactly-is-a-php-script-executed

Comment: No. When you write PHP, your code is being interpreted by the PHP interpreter. This interpreter happens to be written in a different language - C - but which language actually doesn't matter for you. An PHP interpreter could even be written in Java or Assembler. That a lot of PHP function names resemble C standard library function names is a coincidence.

Comment: There is in fact a PHP implementation written in Java: http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/

Answer (score 4):

It is not a C++ code, it is pure C. The PHP library can call C functions just like any other library implemented in C. The code snippet generates a "unique" session ID consisting of the client address, the current time, and a pseudo-random number from some linear congruential generator.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you ended up to that piece of code via the [DEFCON 18: How I Met Your Girlfriend](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=fEmO7wQKCMw#t=444s) lecture? Great talk btw. :-)

Now about the code snippet, it is C and it is part of PHP's code. This exact function handles the generation of PHP session ids. You have the entire function logic explained in the lecture i mentioned above, in case you didn't see it.

As a side not, PHP does not call C functions, instead you call a PHP library function and so it happens that most of those functions are written in C and exposed through PHP. On the other hand `php_session_create_id` does not have an equivalent exposed to PHP, since that one is used internally by PHP when you start a session using [PHP session api](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php).