# Runs every PHP script as a single process or a thread?

Tags: php, multithreading, process

I'm wondering how the php scripts are executed. I know that they are compiled into bytecode, and the bytecode is executed, but I don't know how that bytecode is executed, what executes that bytecode, etc... Can anybody answer that?

Comment: When I open the task manager on Windows (XAMPP), I don't see one process for each PHP script ;)

Comment: PHP itself is executing the compiled script. That's why from the command line you execute PHP and give the script as a parm. The web server essentially does the same, executing PHP and giving it the script name.

Comment: Depends on the SAPI. With Apache+mod_php it's typically one process per script/interpreter. As is it with FastCGI. Other setups (IIS) might use threads. What's the practical relevance for this question?

Comment: I would give you the points mario if I could :-) Please create an answer from your comment! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Depends on the SAPI. With Apache+mod_php it's typically one process per script/interpreter. As is it with FastCGI. Other setups (IIS) might use threads." - mario

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but if I understand you need to know how php executes a script I think there is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720488/how-exactly-is-a-php-script-executed).