# Is this the correct way of putting HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, xhtml, standards, echo, language-features

I'm new to PHP, and most of the time I have been 'echo'ing my HTML. Today, I found this way of doing it, which makes things 1000 times easier:

```
<?php if(get_field('field_name')){ ?>

   <p>HTML can go here without echo'ing it</p>

<?php } ?>
```

But is it an accepted way? It seems to work every time. Thanks.

Comment: It's valid and I prefer this syntax for larger HTML sections without (much) PHP logic.

Comment: This is an important language feature PHP has, [and it has been made exactly for this and in this way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php). Next step is that you first get all variables in order before including the HTML template files. Please do your homework first and take a read of the PHP manual, you'll learn more then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's mostly about how you like to read your code.

With IDE that has autocomplete/code suggestions it is best to use 
`<?php if (...) { ?>` so that autocompletion/suggestion features know when to use html and when php suggestions for your code. And of course it's nice to select coding style that is easy to read later.

As far as I know code highlight wont work, and should not work, inside

```
echo '<div class="c"><h2>...';
```

#### Different coding styles:

Other than what already mentioned there is no big differences. For example using

```
echo "<div>$var1<h1>$var2</h1>...";
```

for inserting variables it is easier (*less writing*), code has smaller footprint and easier to read than this:

```
<?php 
// <= Some code...
?><div><?php echo $var1; ?><h1><?php echo $var2; ?></h1>...
```

#### Short open tags / why not use:

There is also `<?= ?>` shortcut available but I have not used it since it requires PHP configuration (which is not always available/changeable/writable) value `short_open_tag` to be set. However PHP manual says *`Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.`*

See [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/1338846)

and [PHP echo vs PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386620/1338846)

#### And what's found under hood

Everything inside `<?php ?>` is parsed by PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor so someone may say that it takes much more resources to use `echo '<html><here>';` but this is again wrong place to do optimization if you don't have over 100000 `echo`'s or `print`'s + starting `<?php` and ending `?>` takes few instructions too as does `echo` so they are almost same when counting cpu instructions, at least with my installation.

See [How exactly is a PHP script executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2720488/1338846)

and [php.net/manual/en/tokens.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

and [PHP Compiler Internals slides by Sebastian Bergmann](http://www.slideshare.net/sebastian_bergmann/php-compiler-internals)

#### Some tests about performance:

1.77s.: 1 000 000 times `$var = rand(0, 1); echo 'Foo Bar '.$var;`
1.61s.: 1 000 000 times `$var = rand(0, 1); ?>Foo Bar <?php echo $var; ?><?php`
1.83s.: 1 000 000 times `$var = rand(0, 1); echo "Foo Bar $var";`

I really think that it is most about how you like to write/read your code. Sometimes it's better to write and later read
`if (...) { echo "something"; }`
 and sometimes
`<?php if (...) { ?>something<?php } ?>`

Personally I prefer using `echo "...";` when there is a lot of variables or only small piece of text printed out and `?>...<?php` when outputting large chuncks of html or long text with only few variables. This makes code easier to read.

#### About accelerators mentioned in comments:

If I got it right, php does lexical analysis first and passes results to accelerator, from this point of view `?>text<?php` and `echo "text";` has big difference but it still does not change performance within normal website projects.
More clear: Accelerator itself does improve performance but about using `?>text<?php` or `echo "text";` does not make big difference.

#### Final answer:

Yes, it is widely accepted and used but I think (*at least did not find anything clear from PHP docs*) it is still undocumented way, However, as you already know it is not only way. Basically it does just same job as if using echo:

```
if ( get_field('field_name') ) {
   echo "<p>HTML can go here by echo'ing it</p>";
}
```

While trying to find official docs I have read these pages:
[php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
[php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)
[php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.parsing.complex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)
used google, and searched some forums.

It seems that clearly documented *alternate* way is not used so often:

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### UPDATE:

Official documentation about separating `{` and `}` by `<?php` and `?>` within conditional statements is here: [control-structures.intro](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php) and [language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) together documented it, however there is demonstration only for *alternate* way to do it (see above).

Comment: this is useless answer right out of imagination. While in the real life there are NO HTML like `<html>text<h1>text</h1>` and it is NOT easier to read un-highlighted code. for echoing variables one can use `<?=$var2?>`. The last paragraph is a plain nonsense.

Comment: `Everything inside <?php ?> is parsed by PHP` - so, the rest is not being parsed?

Comment: "not like"? what's the difference then? we have an open token, we're looking for a closing one. what's the difference between looking for `<?` in the `?><html><?` statement and looking for `"` in `echo "blah";` one?

Comment: have you ever heard of PHP accelerators, by the way?

Comment: That's why i placed **It's mostly about how you like to read your code.** at heading, I think that there is not much difference between `?>html<?php` and `echo 'html';` but anyway `echo "html";` is different as there `"html"` string is parsed too (not sent straight to output buffer).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Edited a little, any better or worser now? I am still learning and it's good if someone more experienced is willing to help pointing out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is. But it has also become a standard to omit the ending `?>` in every file, so there is no trailing whitespace or line ending in the output.

```
<?php if(get_field('field_name')){ ?>

   <p>HTML can go here without echo'ing it</p>

<?php }
```

If enabled in your php.ini, you can also use short tags (`<?` instead of `<?php`)

Comment: @ilanco: You must be so out of line with real life. There is no PHP 6 and short tags aren't deprecated at all.

Comment: [PHP 6 does not exist](http://smartwebdeveloper.com/php/php-6-features-release-date-hosting-download)

Comment: omitting closing tag in this context doesn't make sense. there are other blocks supposed following this one

Comment: Seems it's the ASP Style Tags that are being phased out, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use the [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: This is good answer. Who has downvoted, please argument the reason.

Comment: Yes, and for that I am more confused now than when I asked the question >_>

Comment: @Phill don't look at votes. just read the answers. they are quite unambiguous.

Comment: @Phill: Anyway "Yes" is answer on your question. This way is correct.