# php - function with multiple tags

Tags: php, html

I am studying wordpress php coding and noticed that these loops are not within a continuous php tag. This is a surprise to me, a beginner, who has read that the statements are delineated by colons or semi colons.

I did not know this works, but obviously it does. Is there a particular reason one would choose this syntax?

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div>
```

Comment: see ternary http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/

Comment: The one reason that I can think of is you can use something like this when you want to escape `php` to insert any html and then continue your php code from where you were previously. Read `Sampo's` answer here for an overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411457/is-this-the-correct-way-of-putting-html-in-php

Comment: you are right, it's rather pointless as-is. but some scripts, especially template scripts do this sort of thing to make it easier for non-coders (e.g. designers who know html/css but not server-side scripting) to add html without messing with php syntax.

Comment: also, you're sort of asking 2 separate questions here: I answered why someone might wrap every line in php tags, now about the colons: It's an alternate way to write a code block for the loop. `while(condition): statement(s) endwhile;` same thing as `while(condition) { statement(s) }`

Comment: different strokes for different folks...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a particular reason one would choose this syntax?

This is called an *alternative syntax*, and it exists solely for code readability/legibility purposes. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for more info.