# In PHP, how does include() exactly work?

Tags: php

How does `include('./code.php');` work? I understand it is the equivalent of having the code "pasted" directly where the include occurs, but, for example:

If I have two pages, `page1.php` and `page2.php`, of which I would need to manipulate different variables and functions in `./code.php`, does `include()` create a copy of `./code.php`, or does it essentially link back to the actual page `./code.php`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking, but what you said at the beginning of your question is accurate. It basically pastes the code in place

Comment: Some explanations about this here http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

If you `include` a text file, it will show as text in the document.

`include` does **not** behave like copy-paste:

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo '**';
$test = 'test';
include 'test.txt';
echo '**';
?>
```

**test.txt**

```
echo $test;
```

The example above will output:

```
**echo $test;**
```

If you are going to include PHP files, you still need to have the PHP tags `<?php` and `?>`.

Also, normally parentheses are not put after `include`, like this:

```
include 'test.php';
```

Comment: In your example, it behaves exactly like copy and paste.

Comment: @Paul - No, it doesn't. If it behaved like copy and paste, the result would be this: `**test**`.

Comment: No, it's a .txt file. Change the extension .php and see what happens.

Comment: @Paul The extension does not matter, the included file will get parsed by php. According to the manual: `The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file. `

Comment: By the way, you can also `return` from an included / required file to return to the including script directly but I have never found any use for that...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean change the extension, I mean wrap it in `<?php ?>`

Comment: Paul if you know the answer why dont you post it and help the OP?

Comment: @Paul I already said to wrap it in PHP tags. No need for another answer.

Comment: @user710502 my answer is in the comments above. Thanks.

Comment: Right, but my point is, it acts just like copy and paste :) It pulls in EXACTLY what is in the file.

Comment: @jeroen The usefulness mostly lies in the ability to actually return something. Consider e.g. a file that contains an array with (e.g. language specific) information: `<?php return array(...);` - this enables you to do `$foo = include('xyz.php');` as well as `$bar = include('xyz.php');`.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff - I think we're just debating the definition of copy and paste :)

Comment: @Niko That's just horrible and is exactly why I have never found any use for it ;-)

Comment: @Paul - Yes, probably. What is your definition?

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff I kind of like the copy-paste analogy with the side-note that you are starting a fresh script so you need to include tags to execute php code ;-)

Comment: @Jocelyn - Just link to the manual. That's the first result, anyway.

Comment: To return an array from a file is what a lot of frameworks do for file based array lists like configuration files. It is a really useful function even if it is only useful 1% of the time.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, when the interpreter hits an `include 'foo.php';` statement, it opens the specified file, reads all its content, replaces the "include" bit with the code from the other file and continues with interpreting:

```
<?php
echo "hello";

include('foo.php');

echo "world";
```

becomes (theoretical)

```
<?php
echo "hello";

?>
{CONTENT OF foo.php}
<?php

echo "world";
```

However, all this happens just in the memory, not on the disk. No files are changed or anything.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you include the `code.php` file. If you include the code.php file into page1.php and then page2.php then you will have access to it's vars and it would effecitvely just "copy and paste" (beaware that is just used to make it easier to understand since the actual dynamics of that are explained above) the file in however if you link like:

```
[code.php]
include('page1.php');
include('page2.php');
```

Then code.php will have access to all of the variables within page1.php but:

- page1.php will not have access to vars in code.php
- page2.php will not have access to vars in code.php

So in order to `inherit` the funcitonality of code.php inot both `page1.php` and `page2.php` be sure to do something like:

```
[page1.php]
include('code.php');

[page2.php]
include('code.php');
```

Then it will work as you expect. So just something to remember there.

Answer (score 0):

Include does not behave like copy paste.

Here is a demonstration using PHP Strict Type Declarations

```
<?php

// function.php (file)

declare (strict_types = 1);

function sum(int $a, int $b)
{
  return $a + $b;
}

/**
 * This will throw TypeError: 
 */

// echo sum(5.2, 5);
```

However, if I call this function from an external file

```
<?php

// caller.php (file)

require_once 'function.php';

/**
 * This will Work instead of throwing a TypeError:
 */

echo sum(5.2, 5);
```

Strict types are enabled for the file that the declare statement was added (function.php)

It does not apply for any function calls made from an external file (caller.php)
 because PHP will always defer to the caller when looking to evaluate strict types.

Require doesn't work like copy/paste

For further understanding,
[Short answer on how PHP script is Executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720488/how-exactly-is-a-php-script-executed/2720501#2720501) &
[A more comprehensible explanation on what include/require really does in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671230/what-does-require-really-do-in-php/34673238#34673238)

Answer (score -1):

```
include('./code.php'); // The Same As Pasting The Code From Code.PHP.
```

It Will Not Redirect To Code.php  In Any Case.