# What does require really do in php

Tags: php, require

I'm new to PHP and facing a problem when I use require.

[image: Folder structure]

- 'Config.php' is in the parent folder
- Model contains test, in which 'LaptopModel.php' is.
- Controller contains the file 'LaptopController.php'

in Config.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
```

in LaptopModel.php:

```
<?php
require '../../Config.php';
```

in LaptopController.php:

```
<?php
require '../Model/test/LaptopModel.php';
```

the question is what the code really is in LaptopController.php when the server process this file?
I think about that in 2 ways, that lead to error or not.

```
<?php
require '../../Config.php';// get the original code from required file
//this cause an error, because from LaptopController.php
//the link to Config.php must be '../Config.php'
```

or it will be:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
//get what was required from Laptopmodel.php file, not the original code
```

Comment: Read it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: thank you. I know about that

Comment: Just a hint: use `__DIR__` for the path of the current file, so you'd always do a require relative to the file it is in, instead of the file it is called from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the question is what the code really is in LaptopController.php when the server process this file?

The file `LaptopController.php` contains exactly what you write in it.
The PHP interpreter doesn't change the content of the file, neither on disk nor when it loads it in memory.

[`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) doesn't work like copy/paste. It works more like a function call (but it doesn't introduce a local scope as functions do).

When the code of `LaptopController.php` is compiled, the statement `require '../Model/test/LaptopModel.php';` is transformed into an opcode that says "load and execute the code in this file".

The code from `LaptopModel.php` is not read and compiled during the compilation phase. It doesn't even check if the path of the file (`../Model/test/LaptopModel.php`) exists. All these happen during runtime, **if** the execution point reaches the `require` statement.

You can verify this easily: place a `require` statement into an `if` statement and make sure the required file has a syntax error (or it doesn't exist). If the `if` branch that contains the `require` is  executed then a fatal error is triggered and the script ends. Otherwise it runs happily because the `require` statement is not executed.

```
// File 'a.php' doesn't exist
if (false) {
    // This statement never runs, no error is triggered
    require 'a.php';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I'm considering. But the compiler out put an error that file not exist. Hmm.

Answer (score 4):

Respective to you questions part what Require really do is simple...
If file is missing or not found It will produce a Fatal Error and halt the execution of the script

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: The real point of his question is how does `require` resolve relative pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, everything is relative to the path of your initially loaded PHP file (your working directory).  Run the command `getcwd()` to see where it is attempting to the load files from.  In this case, it looks like it includes based off the directory where `index.php` is.

> getcwd — Gets the current working directory
>
> **Link** http://php.net/getcwd

Info about include (the current directory they are referring to is the current working directory):

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.
>
> **Link** http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php