# How to fetch from MySql Database when using Include connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using include connection file to connect to the database. My challenge is how do I fetch from the database this is where am stuck.

```
include 'connection.php';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM country';
$results = mysqli_query($sql);
```

Comment: Set the connection `$con` in `connection.php` and use `mysqli_query($con, $sql);`

Answer (score 4):

assume your `connection.php` contain

```
  <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
  ?>
```

So the in your file, you're using `include 'connection.php'` to get the connection. By using [**`include`**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) its act like single page now. Then you've to use it like below

```
  require_once 'connection.php';

  $sql= 'SELECT * FROM country';
  $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql); # add connection string to query
```

---

**Explanation**

when you add this `include 'connection.php';` then whatever the data on parent(**`connection.php`**) file (ex: variable, Functions, etc ..) will come to child.

---

**Links to refer**

1. [In PHP, how does `include()` exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117796/in-php-how-does-include-exactly-work)
2. [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)
3. [include, include_once, require or require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546160/include-include-once-require-or-require-once)

Comment: You should use `include_once` instead of `include` here. Best would be to use `require_once` as query must require existence of `connection.php` to work.

Comment: in progress ..but you add comment before post it ;)