# How to embed mysql in phpdesktop-chrome

Tags: php, mysql, database

**is it possible?**

I want to **embed MySQL** in my project.

```
$path = str_replace('www','',getcwd());
system('"'.$path.'mysql\bin\mysqld.exe');

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mix_pos");

// Create connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  exit();
 }

  echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: Are you using core php or laravel?

Comment: Have you tried using SQLite instead? That's built to be portable.

Comment: I using laravel, but I try PHP,

Comment: I develop my project using MySQL

Comment: @Tayyabmehar how can use mysql

Comment: Laravel has support for SQLite so if you use their database classes (query builder/eloquent) instead of using your own mysql connection using mysqli, it should work the same. Trying to bundle some stand-alone version of mysql will most likely be way more complicated, if even possible in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch from MySql Database when using Include connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533726/how-to-fetch-from-mysql-database-when-using-include-connection)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel project than simply you have to configure your mySql database in .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=190.0.0.1
DB_PORT=4008
DB_DATABASE=testProject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And you can also review config.php file.