# How does PHP works and what is its architecture ?

Tags: php

Guys recently I decided to go back to PHP and do some more complex stuff than a simple log in page. For 3 years I've been programming with Java/JavaEE and have a good understanding of the architecture of of Java Applications. Basically, a virtual machine ( a simple OS process ) that runs compiled code called byte code. a simple Java web server is basically a java application that listens on provided TCP port for Http requests and responds accordingly of course it is more complicated than that but this is its initial work.

Now, what about PHP ? How does it work ? What, in a nutshell, is its architecture.

I googled about this question but in 90% the articles explain how to implement and construct a web application with PHP which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Pretty much the virtual machine and compiling are ... interpreter. The web server architecture depends on the web server, it's not language specific here

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720488/how-exactly-is-a-php-script-executed

Comment: A little off-topic, but if you're starting with PHP, I would recommend you [phptherightway](http://www.phptherightway.com/) as a very useful resource on how to get started properly.

Comment: Well, as Java is more for Enterprise and corporate applications . Websites and online shops are more often writen with PHP and there is a lot of CMS serving purposes such these ones

Comment: PHP is perfectly capable of being used for enterprise applications; the fact that most people use it for simple websites doesn't preclude it from being used for the enterprise

Comment: But java is more like for enterprise and complex application and systems.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The biggest difference between a Java web server and PHP is that PHP doesn't have its own built-in web server. (Well, newer versions do, but it's supposed to be for testing only, it's not a production ready web server.) PHP itself is basically one executable which reads in a source code file of PHP code and interprets/executes the commands written in that file. That's it. That's PHP's architecture in a nutshell.

That executable supports a default API which the userland PHP code can call, and it's possible to add extensions to provide more APIs. Those extensions are typically written in C and compiled together with the PHP executable at install time. Some extensions can only be added by recompiling PHP with additional flags, others can be compiled against a PHP install and activated via a configuration file after the fact. PHP offers the PEAR and PECL side projects as an effort to standardise and ease such after-the-fact installs. Userland PHP code will often also include additional third party libraries simply written in PHP code. The advantage of C extensions is their execution speed and low-level system access, the advantage of userland code libraries is their trivial inclusion. If you're administering your own PHP install, it's often simple enough to add new PHP extensions; however on the very popular shared-host model there's often a tension between what the host wants to install and what the developer needs.

In practice a web service written in PHP runs on a third party web server, very often Apache, which handles any incoming requests and invokes the PHP interpreter with the given requested PHP source code file as argument, then delivers any output of that process back to the HTTP client. This also means there's no persistent PHP process running at all times with a persistent state, like Java typically does, but each request is handled by starting up and then tearing down a new PHP instance.

While Java simply saves persistent data in memory, data persistence between requests in PHP is handled via a number of methods like memcache, sessions, databases, files etc.; depending on the specific needs of the situation. PHP does have opcode cache addons, which kind of work like Java byte code, simply so PHP doesn't have to repeat the same parse and compile process every single time it's executing the same file.

Do keep in mind that it's entirely feasible to write a persistent PHP program which keeps running just like Java, it's simply not PHP's default modus operandi. Personally I'm quite a fan of writing workers for specific tasks on Gearman or ZMQ which run persistently, and have some ephemeral scripts running on the web server as "frontend" which delegate work to those workers as needed.

If this sounds like a typical PHP app is much more of a glued-together accumulation of several disparate components, you'd be correct. Java is pretty self-contained, except for external products like RDBMS servers. PHP on the other hand often tends to rely on a bunch of third party products; which can work to its advantage in the sense that you can use best-of-breed products for specific tasks, but also requires more overhead of dealing with different systems.

Comment: +1 for bringing gearman and zmq (I like rabbitmq as an alternative myself) into the architectural picture

Comment: Also, [take a look at how one can tie the PHP interpreter with the webserver](http://coolpandaca.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/apache-mpm-worker-prefork-mod_php-mod_fcgid-mod_fastcgi-php-fpm-and-nginx/). There are few options...

Answer (score 28):

This is how **PHP** works:

*(one of the best on the Internet)*

[image: PHP internals]

Comment: which compile is used to convert php code to c language @yousha

Comment: @saurabhkamble they using their own Zend Compiler for this

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, PHP as an engine interprets the content of PHP files (typically *.php, although alternative extensions are used occasionally) into an abstract syntax tree. The PHP engine then processes the translated AST and then returns the result given whatever inputs and processing are required.

Below image will depict more information

[image]

Source: [freecodecamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-does-php-works-exactly/296740)