# How programs written in interpreted languages are executed if they are never translated into machine language?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreter, dynamic-languages, compiler-construction

Computers can only understand machine language. Then how come interepreters execute a program directly without translating it into machine language? For example:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!" ;
```

It's a simple Hello World program written in PHP. How does it execute in machine while the machine has no idea what `echo` is? How does it output what's expected, in this case, the string Hello, World!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly is a PHP script executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720488/how-exactly-is-a-php-script-executed)

Comment: The code is interpreted by a program which is most likely compiled into machine code. In the example of an `echo`-like instruction, it might cause the interpreter to call a function it its own program that writes the output.

Comment: In short: there is always module (for php)/framework (like in .net)/platform (Java)/etc  - layer that know how to translate interpreted to machine codes.

For more details - check documentation for programming language you are interested in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many interpreters, including the official PHP interpreter, actually translate the code to a byte code format before executing it for performance (and I suppose flexibility) reasons, but at its simplest, an interpreter simply goes through the code and performs the corresponding action for each statement. An extremely simple interpreter for a PHP-like language might look like this for example:

```
def execute_program(prog)
  for statement in prog.toplevel_statements:
    execute_statement(statement)

def execute_statement(statement):
  if statement is an echo statement:
    print( evaluate_expression(statement.argument) )
  else if statement is a for loop:
    execute_statement(statement.init)
    while evaluate_expression(statement.condition).is_truthy():
      for inner_statement in statement.body:
        execute_statement(inner_statement)
      execute_statement(statement.increment)
  else if ...
```

Note that a big if-else-if statement is not actually the cleanest way to go through an AST and a real interpreter would also need to keep track of scopes and a call stack to implement function calls and returns.

But at its most basic, this is what it boils down to: "If we see this kind of statement, perform this kind of action etc.".

Except for being much more complex, it isn't really any different from writing a program that responds to user commands where the user could for example type "rectangle" and then you draw a rectangle. Here the CPU also doesn't understand what "rectangle" means, but your code contains something like `if user_input == rectangle: [code to draw a rectangle]` and that's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the interpreter is being executed and the code that the interpreter is interpreting just determines what actions the interpreter takes. (If it *was* just compiled to machine code, what would you need the interpreter for?).

For example, I built an automation framework awhile back where we captured reflection metadata on what was occurring at runtime during QA tests. We serialized that metadata to JSON. The JSON was never compiled to anything - it just told the automation engine what methods to call and what parameters to pass. No machine code involved. It wouldn't be exactly correct to say that we were "executing" the JSON - we were executing the automation engine, which was then following the "directions" found in the JSON, but it was certainly *interpreting* the JSON.